# Changing DIV colors using hover and click in JQuery

Tags: jquery, colors, load, click, hover

Could someone please help. I have these two:

I would like the text to change to lightgreen when hovering, white when not hovering, and red when clicked.

```
$(".music").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('color','lightgreen');
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
    }
);

$(".music").click(function () { 
    $('#result').load('album_list_index.php');
    $(this).css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-size': '100%' });
});
```

Thank you in advance

AC

NOTE: ok im sorry i did not make myself clear.

I need the div to be white when not mousedover
I need it to be gree when mouseover
And i need it to be red when clicked, and remain red until another button is clicked.

Thanks everyone for the input, expecialy the add class and remove class cases, that was a good lesson I will use once i master the technique a bit more.

Comment: Why does what you have not work for you? It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/cCAJh/

Comment: beats me, the problem is when i click the item it turns red but then it reverts to white and i hover off it

Comment: That's because the `mouseout` part of `hover` is called setting the element colour back to white.

Comment: Hmmm yes but how do i manage to keep it red once clicked and no longer activate the mouse over ?

Comment: Use classes - see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is when i click the item it turns red but then it reverts to white and i hover off it

If you are looking to have the `click` maintain state you are better off using classes. Try this:

```
a { color: white; }
.active { color: red; }
.hover { color: lightgreen; }
```

```javascript
$(".music").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
);

$(".music").click(function () { 
    $('#result').load('album_list_index.php');
    $(".music").removeClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("hover").addClass("active");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cCAJh/2/)

Comment: <When i use this, which i use for a <li>, the red does not stick once clicked.

Comment: Ok i amended my css to make sure the div #menuitem li included the 
:hover and :active and it worked a treat. Thanks for your help.

Comment: it still turns green when selected over the red, but it will do for now.

Comment: To fix that, give the `active` class a higher precedence, try `a.active { color: red; }`

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS pseudo elements: `:hover` and `:active`.

Or, when using jQuery, use the `.hover()` and `.click()` methods.

Comment: Remember though, that CSS psuedo selectors are not fully supported in older browsers - especially if not used on an `a` element.

Comment: They do not work. I made the classes into id's and still nothing.

Comment: which looked like this

a:link {color:#FF0000;}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;} /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}   /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */

I have the latest firefox, other sections work, such as links, but the menu buttons dont.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap you code in a `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS is recommended...but still with jquery you can do

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".music").mouseover(function() {
           if(!$(this).hasClass('dontchange')){
              $(this).css('color','lightgreen');
           }
        });
        $(".music").mouseout(function() {
               if(!$(this).hasClass('dontchange')){
                $(this).css('color', 'white');
             }
        }

        $(".music").click(function () { 
         $(this).addClass('dontchange');
        $('#result').load('album_list_index.php');
        $(this).css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-size': '100%' });
        });
        });
```

Comment: problem with this ubercooluk is that i need it to remain red when clicked and not change. Im sure its all casting, but i cant get my head around it.